# When did Savage encounter Rip Hunter in Egypt, during his time learning about the sky rocks and killing Kendra and Carter?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In flashbacks in *Legends of Tomorrow* and *Arrow*, it's in Egypt where Vandal Savage learns about the meteors coming and kills Khufu and Chay-Ara. But during his time learning about the sky rocks, he is attacked by Rip Hunter and fights him.  Then guards take Rip and put him in a cell. Savage asks him why he tried to kill him, but Rip refused to speak and left him there to die. Then at some other point, Savage comes to the bed chamber and kills Khufu and Chay-Ara.   When did Savage encounter Rip Hunter in Egypt, during his time learning about the sky rocks and killing Khufu and Chay-Ara? Was it before he killed them or after?  I'm confused when in the timeline it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll lay odds the writers aren't quite sure either.

Since Rip is in his cell for some time, it's possible he arrived before the murders of Khufu and Chay-Ara, and escaped afterwards.  One of Rip's issues is he seems to cause bootstrap paradoxes willy-nilly, accidentally seeming to cause the event he came back to stop.

Comment: so the order is savage telling the king about the sky rocks then him seeing them kissing then rip attacking him then cha-arya getting the knife then Savage talking to rip in the cell then last savage killing Kendra and carter

Comment: That seems a valid order - Savage doesn't seem to know what Rip could want to kill him over, which suggest he hadn't yet killed them, or at least not done anything to warrant such an act of revenge.

Comment: how is that a valid order

Comment: It seems valid, that's all, based on the facts at hand.  Unless we can get a ruling from Berlanti et al, all we can do is guess.

Comment: what do you think the order is  from all of this savage telling the king about the sky rocks then him seeing them kissing then rip attacking him then cha-arya getting the knife then Savage talking to rip in the cell then last savage killing Kendra and carter